# How to debounce a bitmask readings with Arduino? (not buttons...)

Tags: c++, arduino, debouncing

I have this piece of code that I'd like to debounce:
I want to make sure that even after ±1.5 seconds the readings will be the same (if so, do something, otherwise, do something else...).

the winning_check() function gets the bitmask as input and runs inside loop().

```
void winning_check(uint16_t mask) {
if ((mask & 0b11111000000000) == 0b11111000000000) {  // btm row winning sequence
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(BTM_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
} else {
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(BTM_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(BTM_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
if ((mask & 0b00000111110000) == 0b00000111110000) {  // mid row winning sequence
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
} else {
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(MID_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
if ((mask & 0b00000000001111) == 0b00000000001111) {  // top row winning sequence
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(TOP_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
} else {
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(TOP_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(TOP_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
```

}

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
void winning_check(uint16_t mask) {
if ((mask & 0b11111000000000) == 0b11111000000000) {  // btm row winning sequence
    last_debounce_time = millis();
    if ((millis() - last_debounce_time) >= DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS) {
        if ((mask & 0b11111000000000) == 0b11111000000000) {
            digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(BTM_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
        }
    }
} else {
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(BTM_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(BTM_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
if ((mask & 0b00000111110000) == 0b00000111110000) {  // mid row winning sequence
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
} else {
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(MID_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
if ((mask & 0b00000000001111) == 0b00000000001111) {  // top row winning sequence
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(TOP_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
} else {
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(TOP_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(TOP_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
```

}

thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is the new code:
I'd like to mention that the mask belongs to mechanical switches, therefore, they are not being reset until there's a row win detection and then the motor (MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN for example) resets the exact same row.

About resetting the WinningState to LOW, I have a reset function that is being called when a game is over - that is when I reset WinningState.

The new problem is that when I reset the Arduino, start a game, and reaching the right winning mask the code works for the first time with the debounce time we made, but when I do it again it is not counting again, but immediately resets the row's mask...

Another thing that may cause it, is that the else statement is always called. I checked it in the serial monitor using Serial.println().

```
void winning_check(uint16_t mask) {
if (((mask & 0b11111000000000) == 0b11111000000000 || (mask & 0b00000111110000) == 0b00000111110000 || (mask & 0b00000000001111) == 0b00000000001111) && (winning_state == false)) {
    Serial.println("Win detected");
    winning_state = true;
    last_debounce_time = millis();
}
if ((millis() - last_debounce_time) >= DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS && (mask & 0b11111000000000) == 0b11111000000000) {  // btm row winning sequence
    Serial.println("btm row win confirmed");
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(BTM_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
} else {
    Serial.println(".");
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(BTM_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(BTM_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
if ((millis() - last_debounce_time) >= DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS && (mask & 0b00000111110000) == 0b00000111110000) {  // mid row winning sequence
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
} else {
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(MID_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
if ((millis() - last_debounce_time) >= DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS && (mask & 0b00000000001111) == 0b00000000001111) {  // top row winning sequence
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(TOP_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
} else {
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(TOP_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(TOP_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
```

}

Here is the function that calls the sequence:

```
uint16_t get_clowns_state() {
uint16_t clowns_mask = 0;
for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    clowns_mask |= (uint16_t)(digitalRead(clowns_pins[i]) << i);
}

return clowns_mask;
```

}

and inside the loop() I call: winning_check(get_clowns_state());

Comment: You set `last_debounce_time` directly before using it, so `millis() - last_debounce_time` will essentially always be 0

Comment: where else should I set it?
I need to start counting at the moment it detects the right mask

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a state machine it works as follows:

```
 // Global var place before setup()
bool winningState = false;

void winning_check(uint16_t mask) {
    // We check if a winning state is hit
    
if ( ( (mask & 0b11111000000000) == 0b11111000000000 // added bracket
|| (mask & 0b00000111110000) == 0b00000111110000 
|| (mask & 0b00000000001111) == 0b00000000001111 ) // added bracket
&& winningState == false) {  // we hit for the first time herebtm row winning sequence
    winningState = true;
    last_debounce_time = millis();
}
    // we hit for the next 1.5 sec time herebtm row winning sequence
    
    if ((millis() - last_debounce_time) <= DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS && (mask & 0b11111000000000) == 0b11111000000000) { // inversed logic opposite to yours
            digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(BTM_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
        }
    } else {
        winningState = false; // Reset the var
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(BTM_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(BTM_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
    
}
if ((millis() - last_debounce_time) <= DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS &&(mask & 0b00000111110000) == 0b00000111110000) {  // mid row winning sequence
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
} else {
    winningState = false; // Reset the var
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(MID_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
if ((millis() - last_debounce_time) <= DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS && (mask & 0b00000000001111) == 0b00000000001111) {  // top row winning sequence
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(TOP_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
} else {
    winningState = false; // Reset the var
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(TOP_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(TOP_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
```

Before going in your logic we have to do a onetime setting of the timer and set a var that it is not set again until the dtate has changed again. Did a quick write in an editor so if there are any bracket issues I can edit if nescessary.

## Edit

Changed brackets and inversed debounce logic (ditched the OPs logic)

## Second edit

The basic question is:
 should what comes after the if happen after 1.5 seconds only once then use this logic:

```
(millis() - last_debounce_time) >= DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS   // Your logic
```

then the following code applies

```
 if ((millis() - last_debounce_time) >= DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS &&(mask & 0b00000111110000) == 0b00000111110000) {  // mid row winning sequence
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
     winningState = false; // Reset the var
} else {
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(MID_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
```

or should it happen for 1.5 seconds and than change the state:

```
  (millis() - last_debounce_time) <= DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS   // "My" logic
```

than this code applies:

```
if ((millis() - last_debounce_time) <= DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS &&(mask & 0b00000111110000) == 0b00000111110000) {  // mid row winning sequence
    digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
} else {
    winningState = false; // Reset the var
    // digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    if (!digitalRead(MID_ROW_SENSOR_PIN)) digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
}
```

It would help if you apply a state diagramm the following way.

- Detect a state (certain mask)
- do something1 for 1500ms AND state unchanged
- stop something1 if state changes and time < 1500ms -> reset and return
- stop something1 if time is over AND state unchanged --> do something2

Comment: Nothing happens now...
I think you missed restarting WinningState to LOW?

Comment: Since I do not know your logic.I can not provide the point where to reset to LOW, if you provide astate diagramm no problem -I just wanted to give you the basic idea how to structure the overall logic see edit in a minute

Comment: thank you for the help, but the inversion wasn't helpful.
I need to wait the DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS time if the mask is detected, so the previous code was good.

The only problem is that it always calls the else option and that makes the WinningState false which allows the first if statement to happen again

Comment: I'll try to find the right place to reset WinningState to LOW

Comment: Logic do for 1.5 secs something if the winning mask is there? Then millis() - startTtime <= 1500 && winningMask Example   2000-1000 <= 1500 one second elapsed -- believe me thats why it goes for else every time OR is the mask coming only once and then reset? - then use winning state instead of winning mask in the second if see edit

Comment: I found the right place and it works for the first time, but after I win one time it isn't checking anymore for the debounce time. Maybe I should reset the last_debounce_time var as well (although it gets new millis() each time)

Comment: Try my edit 2 solution Or edit your question and post your last code version

Comment: Now the three if statements are the same...
Winning state isn't coming up once. (The mask stays, not resets - it is mechanical switches)

Comment: edit your question and post your last half working code version works one time and also your loop where you call the sequence

Comment: did it. take a look :)

Comment: see replaced second edit and please answer the questions regarding the logic

Comment: Edited your code see insertion of winning_state = false; after peer approval

Answer (score 0):

It needs some updating now that I'm a much better programmer, but the logic is very sound and it does indeed work exceptionally well. Try my `eRCaGuy_EventReader` debounce library from here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_EventReader.

Here's a usage example. Note that you have a bunch of choices: you can act on 1) the **debounced action/event** (at the moment the state changes from false to true, or true to false), OR  2) according to the **debounced state**. Study the example code below and I think you will be able to understand the difference.

Note: this code is also now posted as the main example in the eRCaGuy_EventReader project linked-to above.

```
#include <eRCaGuy_EventReader.h>

// 1500ms, or 1.5 sec debounce delay (last state must remain unchanged for this duration or else the
// debounce is not yet considered "complete")
constexpr unsigned int DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS = 1500; 
constexpr bool EVENT_STATE_WHEN_EVENT_OCCURS = true;

// In this example I create one debouncer. It looks like you will need
// to create several to accomplish what you want. Create one debouncer
// object for each event you'd like to debounce, and follow the pattern
// and usage shown below according to your needs.
eRCaGuy_EventReader debouncer(DEBOUNCE_DELAY_MS, EVENT_STATE_WHEN_EVENT_OCCURS);

void setup()
{

}

void loop()
{
  // Check your masks here
  // ***FILL IN YOUR REAL LOGIC HERE TO CHECK IF THE MASKS ARE THE SAME!***
  bool masks_are_same = true; 

  // Register a new reading
  debouncer.readEvent(masks_are_same);

  // Now get debounced values

  int8_t debounced_action = debouncer.getDebouncedAction();
  switch (debounced_action)
  {
    // No change in the true, debounced event state since last time interpreting the event, or 
    // debounceDelay time not yet elapsed
    case eRCaGuy_EventReader::NO_ACTION:
      // do what you want here
      break;
    // A new event just occurred (debounce delay has elapsed)
    // ie: debounced version of `masks_are_same` has gone from false to true!
    case eRCaGuy_EventReader::ACTION_OCCURRED:
      // do what you want here
      break;
    // A new event just "un-occurred" by going back to its resting state (debounce delay has 
    // elapsed); ie: debounced version of `masks_are_same` has just gone from true back to false!
    case eRCaGuy_EventReader::ACTION_UNOCCURRED:
      // do what you want here
      break;
  }

  // This is the debounced version of `masks_are_same`
  bool masks_are_same_debounced = debouncer.getDebouncedState();
  if (masks_are_same_debounced)
  {
    // do whatever you want if the masks are the same
  }
  else
  {
    // do whatever you want if the masks are different
  }
}
```